# How do I parse data from a json api that has multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

**Objective:** Parse JSON from an API where results are listed across multiple pages.

I am new to JSON and to working with data in general. I want to know how to write a function that will update the url, outputting the results for each page, and stopping when it reaches one that is empty.

This problem here is from a Shopify url displaying JSON data used for trivial purposes and not part of a real application.

https://shopicruit.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=1&access_token=c32313df0d0ef512ca64d5b336a0d7c6

Each page had 5O objects. I'm making an `$.ajax` request to the url but the url has `page=1` as a query,

```
$.ajax({
        url:"https://shopicruit.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=1&access_token=c32313df0d0ef512ca64d5b336a0d7c6",
        method:'get',
        dataType:'JSON'
      }).done(function(response){
```

so the `response` I am only getting back is only for The results of page one (obviously). I know there are more pages b/c if I manually put a `2` in place of the `1` I can see different data. This goes on for multiple pages. I have tried removing the page option, setting it to all and any and these just display page 1.I thought maybe leaving the page option out would cure the problem but it does not.

How do I get all the pages of data with an ajax call?
Is it a function that takes the `$.ajax`call inside of it, that adds page++ and makes a new call for each page? I still don't know how to write that sadly.

The shopify API docs do give some examples on how to display "all data" but I tried to use what they suggested and it did not work so I'm not sure that it's applicable to the problem, but just in case it is– 
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order

Comment: well, you can raise the number of orders you get at once up to 250 `limit=250` ... but you'll need to have some sort of loop that gets the next "bunch" 1 page at a time, until I guess you receive `orders.length < 250` - then don't go to the next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplistic answer - this will get pages until there's clearly no more data - i.e. once a page returns less than `limit` orders

```
function getAllData(page) {
    return $.ajax({
        url:"https://shopicruit.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?page=" + (page || 1) + "&limit=250&access_token=c32313df0d0ef512ca64d5b336a0d7c6",
        method:'get',
        dataType:'JSON'
    }).then(function(response){
        if (page && response.orders.length == 250) {
            return getAllData(page + 1)
            .then(function (more) {
                return response.orders.concat(more)
            })
        }
        return response.orders;
    });
}

getAllData(1).then(function(orders) {
    // orders is an array of orders
});
```

> Note I've used 250 for `limit` to get 250 at a time

I say this is simplistic because, it does get all the data, however, you need to wait until all the data is retrieved before you can use it - this may take too long for your "user experience" - but this should get you to a place you can start

There's logic in the code such that if page is 0, only the first page will be retrieved regardless of how many items are in it - so you could do something like

```
getAllData().then(function(page1data) {
    // do something with page 1
}).then(function() {
    return getAllData(2); // start at page 2
}).then(function(restOfData) {
    // do something with restOfData, pages 2+
});
```

One thing I'm not sure of is

```
.then(function(response){
```

you may need to change this to

```
.then(function(r){
    var response = r[0];
```

I'm not 100% certain of jQuery's `.then` callback arguments

Comment: Sorry for the delay but there some things I'm trying to process. Can we forget about the 250 limit for now? I am not worried about performance so leave it as is to make less confusing.

What is the `(page || 1)`? Is that an `or`, or a `pipe`? I'm still unfamiliar with piping. What U are doing is exactly what I want to do, page++, but I don't really understand how U get there. Or is this simply a syntax that allows me to do what I have wanted to do all along.
I'm don't fully know how to explain what it is that I don't understand.

Comment: you can use 50 in place of 250

Comment: I really like your solution! But it is a bit over my head is taking to dissect. I haven't been able to get it to work, at least not the top block. A breakpoint on `more` comes back as undefined. I think that's what U said U were not sure of. 
This wrecks the `concat` which in turn wrecks the function. I'm not sure why this is happening.